# Can't get jquery date picker to reinitialise after scope updates

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to build a date range picker using Angular and JQuery UI. At the moment I'm trying to handle validation ie. ensuring once an 'end date' has been selected, the 'start date' calendar doesn't allow the user to select a date past this selected end date.

I've put a $watch on the endDate variable, and once that value has been updated I need to be able to reinitialise my date picker, but with a 'maxDate' specified to achieve the above. The problem is that while I can pick up the updated value, I can't seem to reinitialise the date picker with the correct max date.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? This is what I have so far...

**EDIT**: I've added a jsfiddle of my attempt so far [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tj6gyr41/)

**My view**

```
<div id="start-date" class="date-picker" ng-model="vm.startDate" start-date="vm.startDate" end-date="vm.endDate" is-start="true" date-picker></div>
<div id="end-date" class="date-picker" ng-model="vm.endDate" start-date="vm.startDate" end-date="vm.endDate" is-start="" date-picker></div>
```

**My directive**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app').
    directive("datePicker", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: "ngModel",
            scope: {
                startDate: '=',
                endDate: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

                var updateModel = function (dateText) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
                    });
                };

                scope.options = {
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                    onSelect: function (dateText) {
                        updateModel(dateText);
                    },
                    maxDate: null
                };

                elem.datepicker(scope.options);

                scope.$watch('endDate', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (!!newValue) {
                        scope.options.maxDate = new Date(2017, 2, 28); // Hard coded value for testing

                        elem.datepicker(scope.options);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: What's wrong with the native solutions? (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker or http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepickerPopup)

Comment: I wasn't even aware of those solutions - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I couldn't get it to work smoothly with JQuery UI. I opted instead to use: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker

I managed to get exactly the result I was looking for with the above - hopefully this helps someone attempting to do the same as me!